# play 2.6 auto-reload doesn't show changes after first compile

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.6

When I execute `sbt run` and refresh, `localhost:9000` will show my changes. If i change something else, save my project and hit refresh again `localhost:9000` does not show my changes. If i try `sbt ~run` I can see sbt recompiling every time i change a file and save, however refreshing `localhost:9000` does not show any updates. Only if I terminate the sbt process and restart it can I see my changes.

My setup:

Windows 8.1

Play 2.6

sbt 1.0.2

scala 2.12.3

Intellij 2017.2.5

Comment: I am having the same problem. For me, it happens mostly when I amake a change to a view. Play hot reload does not seem to be able to catch it unless I restart the app

Comment: Looks like a known issue https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/N1ozDOe5sU4/jKkSLhZ1AQAJ

Comment: Can confirm the answer in the thread that rolling back to sbt to 0.13.16 fixes the problem. You do this in /project/build.properties

Comment: Try with Play 2.6.7 please.

Comment: As @marcospereira suggested, try again with the latest release of Play. File reloading issues is something that we're actively working on.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating Play's file watcher by adding this to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lightbend.play" %% "play-file-watch" % "1.1.3"
```